# Problem configurating the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, document-configuration

I had set the **Table Of Contents (TOC)** to display as shown in the attached screenshot, with the **chapter number inside a square box**.

Everything was going perfect until the book surpassed 9 chapters. There the problem manifested itself; that is, the problem arises when the chapter number became 2 digits. Obviously, as seen in the image, the undesirable effect that I want to correct is the **misalignment of the box that contains the chapter number**.

Actually, **the boxes that are more out of place are the ones that contain single-digit numbers**, since they invade more the left margin. These boxes should be aligned to the left, but respecting the left margin.

On the other hand, I would also like **the chapter numbers to be perfectly centered within the box that contains them**, as well as **optimize the code so that the spaces to the right of the subsection numbers adjust automatically** depending on the width of the numbers.

**A minimal working example __________________________________________________**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}

% ------------------------------<<< Set up TOC >>>-------------------------------

\titleformat{\chapter}{\large \bfseries}{\filright \fboxrule 3pt \framebox[1.8em][c]{\thechapter}}{16pt}{\large}

%By https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/239495/c-peters:
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{2em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{2em}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hskip-1.6em
    \filright \fboxrule 3pt \fbox{$\mathstrut${\Large~~~}}}%[1.8em][c]{}}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S \hspace{6pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpresnum{$ \bullet $ \hspace{2pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{4em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{4em} %Sets the spacing of the title after the subsection number. The gap varies discretely depending on the number of sections and subsections, I would approach it starting with the minimum gap, that is, with \renewcommand \cftsubsecnumwidth {2.5em}, and once the document is completed you can see if it is necessary to increase the parameter of this command. 
% END _____________________________________________

% -----<<< Prints the part title between two horizontal lines >>>------

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\Large\hrule} %add line above part
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\\\hrule}%add line below part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}%get rid of part page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{4mm}%control line spacing
% END _____________________________________________

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{FOREWORD.}
    \chapter*{FOREWORD.}
    
    \part{Part Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 2.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 3.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 4.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 5.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 6.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 7.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 8.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 9.}
    \section{Section Example 1.}
    \subsection{Subsection Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 10.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 11.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 12.}
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC]

[image: TOC]

[image: TOC]

Comment: All this bold text in your question makes the text hard to read.

Comment: The intention is just the opposite: to highlight the most notable points facilitating a faster understanding.

Comment: but that doesn't work. There is a reason why in LaTeX \emph produces italics and not bold. I also think that your question would gain if you would shorten it and if you would remove all this tikz and pstricks code. That is not relevant to describe a problem with two digits numbers.

Comment: But I use bold only for ordinary text, not for LATEX. In any case, I think this is not relevant... I have further simplified the preamble, testing which packages could be removed in the minimal working example. But this is also not relevant since in a working example it's just copied and pasted, and I think the problem is well defined (the problem is independent of the packages I use).

Comment: you can do what you want. But for my decision if I work on a question or not this things matters. I prefer questions that are short and to the point and don't shout at me with lots of bold text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

Added a patch at the end of the preamble to align the boxes and center the chapter numbers. (Only the relevant packages were kept.)

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 
 
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
    
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{tocloft}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\large \bfseries}{\filright \fboxrule 3pt \framebox[1.8em][c]{\thechapter}}{16pt}{\large}

\newlength{\chapternW}\setlength{\chapternW}{3.0em}% width of the chapter number box <<<<<<<<<<<<   

\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{\chapternW}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{\chapternW} %changed <<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{\chapternW} %changed <<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S \hspace{6pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpresnum{$ \bullet $ \hspace{2pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{4em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{4em} %Sets the spacing of the title after the subsection number
    
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\Large\hrule}%add line above part

\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\\\hrule}%add line below part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}%get rid of part page numbers

\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{4mm}%control line spacing

%************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@chapter{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
{\protect\numberline{\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt} \framebox[2em]{\thechapter}}#1}{}{}
%**************************************

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{FOREWORD.}
    \chapter*{FOREWORD.}
    
    \part{Part Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 2.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 3.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 4.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 5.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 6.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 7.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 8.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 9.}
    \section{Section Example 1.}
    \subsection{Subsection Example 1.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 10.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 11.}
    \chapter{Chapter Example 12.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Simon. Amazing!. Now yes, everything has been placed in its place. Very good solution and very well commented. I will keep your name in the LATEX code of my future book. Just one detail: I would like the subsection number to be followed by a period. Surely this is not a challenge for you! Best regards from Spain!.

Comment: @Jesús Álvarez Lobo Thank you for your feedback !  Try  `\renewcommand\cftsubsecaftersnum{.}`

Comment: OK!. Thanks again, Simon!

Comment: I have learned something! I have also managed to put the period at the end of the section number: \renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}

Comment: Simon, what I have not been able to put is the point after the Roman numeral of part.

Comment: Simon, in the complete document everything is already perfect. Not a single point is missing or leftover! Greetings!!!.